# Neo4J throws ForsetiClient exceptions for commands run in same transaction

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a strange issue thats seen at random times for following 2 queries.

```
MATCH (n:TempLagNode {lag_sys_id: "00:05:9A:30:A0:22"})-[:HAS_TEMP_L2_LAG_INTF ]->(lag:TempL2LagInterface {oper_key: 222})
  -[:HAS_TEMP_L2_LAG_MBR_INTF ]->(member:TempL2LagMemberInterface {oper_port: 1})
DETACH DELETE member

MATCH (n:TempLagNode)-[:HAS_TEMP_L2_LAG_INTF]->(lag:TempL2LagInterface)
WHERE size((lag)-->())=0 AND size((lag)<--())<=2
DETACH DELETE lag
```

Both the commands are run in same transaction. But running above sequence multiple times leads to following exception (it passes mostly but fails some times):

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.neo4j.driver.v1.exceptions.TransientException: ForsetiClient[4] can't acquire ExclusiveLock{owner=ForsetiClient[1]} on NODE(205), because holders of that lock are waiting for ForsetiClient[4]. 410  Wait list:ExclusiveLock[411 Client[1] waits for [4]]
```

Can someone comment whats causing above?

Comment: Are you sure they are in the same transaction? Also, even if they are, can multiple transactions be running simultaneously?

Comment: Yes they are. Until transaction is committed, they are in same transaction scope. It works most of the times so its a random issue.

Answer (score 1):

See [this article](https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/explanation-of-error-deadlockdetectedexception-forseticlient-0-cant-acquire-exclusivelock/) for an illustration of the deadlock situation that can cause this error.

When you `DETACH DELETE` a node, that causes an attempt to delete that node and all its relationships, which causes an attempt to place a Write-Lock on each of them. In addition, a relationship deletion attempt causes an attempt to place a Write-Lock on each of its end nodes.

Here is one sequence of events that can cause a deadlock with your 2 queries:

1. Transaction 1 starts executing `DETACH DELETE member`. This starts out by placing a Write-Lock on the `member` node.
2. Transaction 2 starts executing `DETACH DELETE lag`. This starts out by placing a Write-Lock on the `lag` node.
3. Transaction 1 starts deletion of the relationships of the `member` node, which in turn causes an attempt to Write-Lock the same `lag` node that Transaction 2 already has a lock on.
4. Transaction 2 starts deletion of the relationships of the `lag` node, which in turn causes an attempt to Write-Lock the same `member` node that Transaction 1 already has a lock on.

The result is a deadlock.

As the above article states, you can retry queries that experience these kinds of `TransientException`s, since it is unlikely that a retry will also experience a deadlock.

Answer (score 1):

Found the root cause. When 2 different threads try to run same Neo4J query (hence different TX), above deadlocks are seen. Fixing them to lock properly between threads fixed the issue.

Comment: That's the only reason I could see an issue. Which is why I asked... :-).